# why android emulators are very slow on my computer

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

is it my computer's hardware limitation?  it has 1024 megabytes of ram  2200 x 2 dual core amd cpu  i can't develop any android.  the emulators are heavy what can I do?  i download old sdk and newer ones but it still the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1 gigabyte of ram isn't enough. Eclipse alone would take up almost a two-thirds of that
(mine takes up 900mb - tweaked in eclipse.ini), and a 2.2 Emulator on HomeScreen would take up about 200mb. Unless you don't open anything else while coding - firefox, chrome (that ram sucker of a browser), mail client, chat client, etc., you're only a pinch below the limit.

The best you can do outside of upgrading memory is to run emulator in QVGA (in AVD Manager, click on your virtual device, click edit, under Skin, change Built-in to QVGA. But it would only do so much - you need at least 4 gig to go smoothly with all other apps open.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the x86 (Atom) system image it's faster than the arm images

See this [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-tm-android-x86-emulator-image-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I have much better PC than you and even I have difficulties with emulating some OpenGL ES applications that I develop for android. 
You must understand that emulating a CPU which is different than current architecture is very hard to do and as such very hard to do very optimized. Running machine code for ARM on x86 must bring some delays in running it. Conversion and repacking back and forth.

I would rather try to use your own Android device for testing and debuging purposes instead of emulator. It runs in real time and it will be better for you if you don't want to upgrade your CPU and RAM.